# How to assign "Trajectory Smoothing Window Size" inside VMD Tcl script

Tags: molecular-dynamics, vmd

Currently in my VMD display, I define the *Trajectory Smoothing Window Size*
in the dialog box as below.

Figure below is for `protein` selection, the *Trajectory Smoothing Window Size* as 5.

[image]

How can I encode that to Tcl script?

The current Tcl script I have is this (`vmd.tcl`):

```
display projection Orthographic
display rendermode GLSL
mol modselect 0 0 protein
mol modstyle 0 0 NewCartoon 0.300000 10.000000 4.100000 0
mol modcolor 0 0 Structure
mol addrep 0
mol modselect 1 0 resname PEP
mol modstyle 1 0 Licorice 0.300000 12.000000 12.000000
mol modcolor 1 0 Name
```

And I'd like to incorporate the *Trajectory Smoothing Window Size* into it,
for both `protein` and `resname PEP`.

Later I execute it as:

```
$ vmd md.gro md_noPBC.xtc -e vmd.tcl
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `mol smoothrep x y z`

where

1. `x` is the `molid`
2. `y` is the representation number (starts from 0)
3. `z` is the `trajectory smoothining window size`

In your case, for `molid 0` and for `protein` representation and `trajectory smoothing window size` of 5, the command will be

`mol smoothrep 0 0 5`

and for representation of `resname PEP`, the command will be

`mol smoothrep 0 1 5`

Comment: does the `y` value follow the order on the Graphical Representation display?

Comment: @scamander yes. Mind, it doesn’t start from 1, instead it starts from 0